# shell script comparison of values

Tags: linux, shell

In  shell script how can i compare these kind of variable

```
  echo $du   //170G
  echo $expected_du // 40G

   if [ $expected_du -le $du ]
   then
        echo "$du exceeded";
   fi
```

Comment: How do you want 170M to compare to 40G?  It would probably be easier if you construct $du without the suffixes.

Comment: how to construct without the suffixes this is wht i was doing df -h|awk {'print $2'}|head -n3|awk 'NF{s=$0}END{print s}' and the output is 170G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-k` flag to `du`, which returns the size in kilobytes  without any units.  For example:

```
$ du -ks /tmp
1068    /tmp
```

Now you have a number that you can compare using `-le`.

You could also multiple things out in your script:

```
case $du in
  *K)   du_k=${du%K};;
  *M)   du_k=$(( ${du%M} * 1024 ));;
  *G)   du_k=$(( ${du%G} * 1024 *1024 ));;
  *T)   du_k=$(( ${du%T} * 1024 *1024 * 1024 ));;

  *[0-9])   du_k=$du;;

  *)    echo "What?"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

echo $du_k
```